# How do I show Microsoft Edge's user agent styles?

Tags: css, user-agent, microsoft-edge

I can't inspect User Agent Styles in Microsoft Edge developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

F12 > DOM Explorer > Computed > Display user styles only OFF